# Merge 2 Pointlayers with same coordinates but different attributes in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, point, merge

I have two layers with points who have exactly the same coordinates but different attribute fields. I would like to merge the tow layers so that I only have one point at each location who has the attributes from both layers. 
I have the feeling that this should be very easy but I just cannot do it and cannot find any expalanation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **Join attributes by location** tool from the toolbar (*Vector* > *Data Management Tools* > *Join attributes by location*).

Select the *Keep all records* option to make sure the output layer receives all attributes related to each specific point:

[image: Join attributes by location]

Hope this helps!